# Is there a way to get improved MySQL syntax highlighting over what vim offers out of the box?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, filetype-php

Having spent a bit of time sorting out my colorscheme for my php files, I'd now like to "prettify" my sql.  (I blame lockdown).

My sql is spread liberally through my php files, but I've noticed the problems I have largely exist even if I'm editing a pure sql file.

I've used `ft=mysql` so I'm using `mysql.vim` rather than `sql.vim`.  I'm actually using neovim rather than vim, but I believe the problems exist in both.

So, what problems?  Two main ones jump out:

**Problem 1**

I'd like to highlight table and column names, but unless I escape them with backticks vim doesn't have a clue that they ARE table and column names.  I suspect without somehow importing a schema that this would be a non-trivial fix, too!

My database and my php code exist on the same box, so IS there a plugin that would compare my SQL queries to my schema?

You can "highlight" all table/column names by applying a base color to the whole shebang, which then gets overwritten in the case of keywords/functions etc.  But if you have a column name inside a function call, it'll inherit the function color, which is an unusual choice.  Again, if you use backticks this does "fix" this problem.

But I'm loathe to go through hundreds of queries wrapping every table/column identifier in backticks just so I can choose what color to show them!

**Problem 2**

If you use `let php_sql_query` so that you get sql syntax inside PHP strings, you'll find that it doesn't look for a leading `SELECT`/`INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`/`CREATE` to suggest that you ARE in a SQL string, so you end up with any SQL keywords being highlighted in **every** string in your codebase.  Horrible.

The workaround to that seems to be to use `let php_sql_heredoc` instead, and to use heredoc notation for any queries (and not for anything else.  Workable, but like the backticks, that now requires me to add `<<<SQL` and `SQL` around every single one of my queries.  Not only is this tedious but if the query is short and simple it's... ugly!

I mean, this doesn't feel like the hardest problem in the world, and it's not like there's any shortage of people using mysql/php in Vim, so I feel someone must have "solved" this by now... but my googling hasn't thrown up anything of any use.

Please point me in the right direction, if such a thing exists.  If not... why not?

Thank you

Comment: [Check this out..](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/6ld9a1/some_nice_syntax_secrets_for_php_that_i_found/) They got syntax highlight for those keywords. Did you try other colorscheme?

Comment: If you read my question through you'll see that I've already used those options and am looking for something better

Comment: I know, but you said it doesn't look for `SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/CREATE` which isn't true for that setting

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't highlight them, but it doesn't use their presence to indicate that the rest of the string is probably sql. So if you have the string `$s = 'click to delete item';` then delete will be highlighted.

Comment: Since asking the question I've managed to improve things a lot for myself... I just have one project I work on, and for consistency I still use the fairly questionably naming conventions and mysql style that I always have.  So SELECT etc are *always* in capitals.  Table names are *always* prefixed with TBL_.  Table aliases are always [A-Z]{2,4}.  Column names are *always* [a-z][A-Z][a-z]+  (nUser, sUsername, fConversionRate etc etc).  So in short I've learnt how to edit my own syntax file to create my own syntax rules to apply my own colorscheme to, and it works pretty well.

Comment: I get all the highlighting I want, with no extraneous highlighting in other strings in my PHP code.

Comment: @Codemonkey if you found a solution to your problem your are welcome to answer your own question, this might be useful for another user :)

Comment: Instead I did the worst possible thing @statox  - spent a while learning how to do what I wanted, created my own php.vim file, then migrated to a new server, and now I realise I didn't move this file over.  No backup, no documentation.  Tits.

Comment: Too bad... but that's a good opportunity to move your dotfiles to a git repository (or any version control system actually) to avoid repeating your mistakes :)

Comment: Agreed - most of my stuff is in a repo (code, nginx conf etc), but not various things in my home directory. Always been on my "todo" list.